# Communication among fragment and activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm implementing fragments in my app. Referring to this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity),
there is written I should use `getActivity()` to access activity methods but also (in the next paragraph) I should declare an interface in the fragment and let activity implement it.
Now, the second way is used for callback methods like events, but I can also use `getActivity().onSomeEventHappened()`, can't I?

Could someone explain me the differences? Because I cannot see differences among them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in the end result if you know that getActivity() will always return the type of Activity you expect.

However using interfaces is a good practice because it decouples your Fragments from a particular implementation of an Activity. So later on in the future if you decide to use your fragments with a different activity, all you have to do is have that activity implement your fragments Interface to be alerted of any fragment events.

You should always strive to have decoupled components if you want an application that is easy to extend without side effects.

Answer (score 1):

You can not always simply call `getActivity().onSomeEventHappened()`. Just imagine this case: You have two fragments, one with ListView and other which shows image based on listItem selected. In second fragment you cannot just call `getActivity().onListItemClicked()`, because your activity has no such method, but if activity implements interface and catches those event from the first fragment, then you are able to pass info about event to the second fragment and how the right image.

Comment: Ok, but if I know that the activity returned by `getActivity()` is an activity I declared, I can cast the returned reference and use the methods of my activity, right? In this way, the interface is useless doesn't it?